# How do I disable my one of my two Radeon graphics cards?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. The laptop has two video cards:

> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.[AMD/ATI] **Sumo** [Radeon HD 6480G]
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller:Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] **Whistler** [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]

I know that one of them is broken, so I need to try to turn off Whistler. How can I do that, is it possible?

The problem is, that Ubuntu doesn't even boot with video cards enabled. So I went to grub and disabled them like so: `radeon.modeset=0`. But this disables both cards, because both of them are Radeon. Now at that point I can get into Ubuntu. But as there are no video cards enabled, there are no drivers and there is no  `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` directory to switch my cards.

How can I turn it off?

Comment: “The problem is, that Ubuntu doesn't even boot with video cards enabled.” Not too sure what this means? Do you mean that because one of the cards is broken, both are enabled and then you can’t boot?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu stuck on login screen. So I cant get in Gnome when both cards are enabled.